# controlling the number of bytes ready to read from Audio card in QT

Tags: c++, qt, audio, buffer

In QT I can define an Audio input as:

```
m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_Inputdevice, m_format, this);
m_input = m_audioInput->start();
```

In my application I would like to use a mic and read from audio card.

Now if I want to see how many bytes are ready to read from Audio buffer I use:

```
qint64 len = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
```

It looks like the `len` is a function of sampling rate and number of bits per sample.
My question is that is there a way to control `len`, without changing the sampling rate? In other words I would like to control the audio card such that it reads data in shorter blocks and emits the ready signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the audio card by setting up proper format parameters e.g., frequency, sample size. For this you need to use `QAudioFormat` class.

Other than this, there is no other way to control audio card from Qt.

[Class Reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qaudioformat.html).

Example from the [reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qaudioinput.html):

```
QFile outputFile;   // class member.
QAudioInput* audio; // class member.

outputFile.setFileName("/tmp/test.raw");
outputFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate );

QAudioFormat format;

// set up the format you want, eg.
format.setFrequency(8000);
format.setChannels(1);
format.setSampleSize(8);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
    qWarning()<<"default format not supported try to use nearest";
    format = info.nearestFormat(format);
}

audio = new QAudioInput(format, this);
QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(stopRecording()));
audio->start(&outputFile);
// Records audio for 3000ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if bytesReady() emits a ready signal after let's say every 640 bytes are ready, but I read only 320 byes after seeing the emitted signal, then if I read another 320 bytes, it will be a continuation of data, i.e first read, reads from location 0 to 319 and second read reads from location 320 to 639?

Comment: @TJ1: Yes, you will read data in continuation. For example, after you've read first 320 bytes, if you again read 320 bytes from the buffer, it will be the next 320 bytes in the order. But in that case, you will soon run into audio buffer overflow. Better read all the data from the audio buffer at once, then store it in some intermediate buffer of yours. From there you can then read as much data as you like in one go without causing audio buffer overflow. You still need to make your intermediate buffer as large as needed so that you don't run into overflow here.

Comment: Is there any other way to control the size of bytes that are ready to read from any other C++ library not just QT?

Comment: @TJ1: You cannot control how your audio hardware works (well, not directly, especially not from your application of course). You can use the formats that your audio driver supports. If your audio driver supports a format such that whenever a ready signal is fired, it provides you with 320 bytes of audio data, then you are able to do it. If it doesn't, then you can't. That's why people use intermediate buffer while audio recording/playback.